# Doctrine 2 association mapping always returns null

Tags: sql, doctrine-orm

I'm having an issue getting an association to populate in my Doctrine entity. The entity gets populated fully with the single exception of the association, even when set to eager loading. I have other similar associations working so I suspect there is some fundamental understanding that I'm missing here.

What I am trying to do here is populate `$s` in the entity with the `S` object, known as `s` in the query. I apologize in advance for the naming, but I've had to strip out anything potentially identifying as this is part of proprietary code.

Here's the bulk of my `SHealth` entity class:

```
// -------------------------------------------------------------------
// ENTITY FOR SHealth
// -------------------------------------------------------------------
/**
 * Used for tracking the current health of shares.
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="SHealthRepository")
 * @Table(name="s_health")
 */
class SHealth
{
    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer", name="s_id")
     */
    protected $sId;

    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer", name="l_id")
     */
    protected $lId;

    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="smallint", name="s_type")
     */
    protected $sType;

    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="smallint", name="s_subtype")
     */
    protected $sSubtype;

    /**
     * @Column(type="smallint", name="health_status")
     */
    protected $healthStatus;

    /**
     * @Column(type="datetime", name="update_time")
     */
    protected $updateTime;

    /**
     * Scalar value
     */
    protected $active;

    /**    
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="S")
     * @JoinColumns({
     *   @JoinColumn(name="l_id", referencedColumnName="l_id"),
     *   @JoinColumn(name="s_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    protected $s;

    // [Accessors and mutators omitted]
}
```

Here's a snippet of the associated repository class:

```
// -------------------------------------------------------------------
// Repository fetch function
// -------------------------------------------------------------------

$rtime_check = !$include_rtimed ? " AND s.rtime IS NULL" : "";
$limit_check = $limit > 0 ? " LIMIT " . $limit : "";

$sql = "SELECT
        s.l_id,
        s.id AS s_id,
        COALESCE(s_health.s_type, s.type) AS s_type,
        COALESCE(s_health.s_subtype, 0) AS s_subtype,
        s_health.health_status,
        s_health.update_time,
        (s.enabled AND
            COALESCE(orsr.status, orsh.status, 0) > 0) AS active
        FROM s

        LEFT JOIN s_health ON
            s.l_id = s_health.l_id AND
            s.id = s_health.s_id AND
            s.type = s_health.s_type AND
            s_health.s_subtype = 0

        LEFT JOIN orsr ON
            s.l_id = orsr.l_id AND
            s.se_id = orsr.se_id AND
            orsr.status IN ([omitted])

        LEFT JOIN orsh ON
            s.l_id = orsh.l_id AND
            s.id = orsh.s_id AND
            orsh.status IN ([omitted])

        WHERE s.l_id IN (:d_ids)
        {$rtime_check}
        GROUP BY s.l_id, s.id
        {$limit_check}";

    // Map the SQL result columns to class properties.
    $rsm = new ResultSetMappingBuilder($this->_em);
    $rsm->addRootEntityFromClassMetadata(SHealth::class, 's_alias');
    $rsm->addScalarResult('active', 'active');

    $query = $this->_em->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);
    $query->setParameter("d_ids", $d_ids);

    $results = $query->getResult();

    // Inject aggregate function results into the resulting object.
    $health_objects = [];
    foreach ($results as $result)
    {
        $health_object = $result[0];
        $health_object->setActive($result['active']);
        $health_objects[] = $health_object;
    }

    return $health_objects;
```

Finally, here's the `S` class, with some members removed:

```
// -------------------------------------------------------------------
// ENTITY FOR S
// -------------------------------------------------------------------
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="s")
 */
class S
{
    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer", name="l_id")
     */
    protected $lId;

    /**
     * @Column(type="integer", name="se_id")
     */
    protected $seId;

    /**
     * @Column(type="smallint")
     */
    protected $type;

    /**
     * @Column(type="boolean")
     */
    protected $enabled;

    /**
     * @Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $rtime;

    // [Accessors and mutators omitted]
}
```

I have all of the necessary getters and setters, and all the necessary database data is present in both tables so there shouldn't be any issue with the join columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not fully sure what prevented the native query from working, but I've changed direction in solving this problem. I'm posting as an answer in the slim chance someone else will have a similar problem in the future.

What I wound up doing was scrapping the `SHealth` repository entirely, and instead I am simply using an `S` repository. I went this route because my native query was selecting from `s` primarily anyway. So, instead of trying to put the results of a select from and join `s` onto the `sHealth` entity (using a native query), I used a simpler DQL query from the other side of the relationship.

The following is my new repository fetch function, this time in the `S` repository, which achieves essentially the same thing as my native query in the question:

```
$query_builder = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
$query_builder->select('s, CASE WHEN s.enabled = TRUE AND COALESCE(orsr.status, orsh.status, 0) != 0 THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END AS active')
    ->from(S::class, 's')
    ->leftJoin(
        ORSR::class,
        'orsr',
        \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH,
        "s.lId = orsr.lId AND
        s.seId = orsr.seId AND
        orsr.status IN ([omitted])"
    )
    ->leftJoin(
        ORSH::class,
        'orsh',
        \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH,
        "s.lId = orsh.lId AND
        s.id = orsh.sId AND
        orsh.status IN ([omitted])"
    )
    ->where('s.lId IN (:d_ids)')
    ->setParameter('d_ids', $d_ids);

// If rtimed items were not requested, exclude them.
if (!$include_rtimed)
{
    $query_builder->andWhere(
        $query_builder->expr()->isNull('s.rtime')
    );
}

// Apply limit if specified.
if (!is_null($limit))
{
    $query_builder->setMaxResults($limit);
}

$s_list = $query_builder->getQuery()->getResult();

// Inject aggregate function results into the resulting object.
$results = [];
foreach ($s_list as $row)
{
    $this_s = $row[0];

    $this_s->setActive($row['active']);
    $results[] = $this_s;
}

return $results;
```

I added this field to my `S` entity:

```
/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="SHealth", mappedBy="s")
 * @JoinColumns({
 *   @JoinColumn(name="l_id", referencedColumnName="l_id"),
 *   @JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="s_id")
 * })
 */
protected $health;
```

And, I altered `sHealth`'s association to inverse the one in `S`:

```
/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="S", inversedBy="health")
 * @JoinColumns({
 *   @JoinColumn(name="l_id", referencedColumnName="l_id"),
 *   @JoinColumn(name="s_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
protected $s;
```

The moral of the story is that instead of trying to perform a right join for an association using a native query, it may be beneficial to reverse the entities and left join (in this case via association using DQL) instead.

Answer (score 0):

If your joined columns are part of the entity identifier, you should try once like this:

1) Mark the association as part of identifier with an `@Id` annotation:

```
/**   
 * @Id
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="S")
 * @JoinColumns({
 *   @JoinColumn(name="l_id", referencedColumnName="l_id"),
 *   @JoinColumn(name="s_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
protected $s;
```

2) remove the other two columns:

```
/**
 * @Id
 * @Column(type="integer", name="s_id")
 */
protected $sId;

/**
 * @Id
 * @Column(type="integer", name="l_id")
 */
protected $lId;
```

Comment: I'm not able to use a single join column, as the target entity's primary key is a composite key. `id` is not unique without also having `l_id`.

Comment: @BrandonJ.Dusseau Ah, I see that now, I missed that part. I will look once more.

Comment: @BrandonJ.Dusseau I updated, not sure if this works with two join columns though...

Comment: I tried it, and it threw an exception:
"It is not possible to map entity '[Omitted]\S' with a composite primary key as part of the primary key of another entity"

Comment: OK. Too bad, but my guess is that the problem is related to this. You map both two fields as well as the join columns of your relationship to the same  database columns. Not sure if doctrine is handling this correctly. Did you validate your schema? The doctrine schema validator will probably tell you that there are problems with this mapping.

Comment: Unfortunately I have not been able to get the CLI tools to work with our setup, but running the "manual" validation (http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/tools.html#runtime-vs-development-mapping-validation) did not return any errors.

On another note, I am successfully using multiple join columns in a OneToOne mapping in another entity.

Comment: But are those also identifier columns like in this case? I will have another look tomorrow...

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. I've changed directions and put the new information in an answer.